# Parameters for OpenCV eye detector in iPhone

Tags: iphone, opencv, face-detection, eye-detection

I am trying to map a 3d glass onto a face using iPhone. I am using following OpenCV eye detection. However eye detection is not very robust. A little turn in the face or if i m looking down at the camera when eyes become a little narrow eye detection does not work. Even in frontal face it detects only in half the frames. I read many places that tweaking certain parameters can help or pre processing of the image. However i am not able to get right combination. Following is the pre-processing and parameters I am using. If anyone can suggest/share better parameters please help. Thanks

Getting gray scale image from `pixelBuffer`-image. Then `processFrame` is called:

```
 if (format == kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange) {
            // For grayscale mode, the luminance channel of the YUV data is used
            CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
            void *baseaddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0);

            cv::Mat mat(videoRect.size.height, videoRect.size.width, CV_8UC1, baseaddress, 0);

            [self processFrame:mat videoRect:videoRect videoOrientation:videoOrientation];

            CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0); 
        }
        else if (format == kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA) {
            // For color mode a 4-channel cv::Mat is created from the BGRA data
            CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
            void *baseaddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer);

            cv::Mat mat(videoRect.size.height, videoRect.size.width, CV_8UC4, baseaddress, 0);

            [self processFrame:mat videoRect:videoRect videoOrientation:videoOrientation];

            CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);    
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Unsupported video format");
        }
```

Initializing the classifiers:

```
    NSString * const kFaceCascadeFilename = @"haarcascade_frontalface_alt2";
    NSString * const kEyesCascadeFilename = @"haarcascade_eye";
```

processFrame: Doing the detection

```
- (void)processFrame:(cv::Mat &)mat videoRect:(CGRect)rect videoOrientation:(AVCaptureVideoOrientation)videOrientation
{
    // Shrink video frame to 320X240
    cv::resize(mat, mat, cv::Size(), 0.5f, 0.5f, CV_INTER_LINEAR);
    rect.size.width /= 2.0f;
    rect.size.height /= 2.0f;

    // Rotate video frame by 90deg to portrait by combining a transpose and a flip
    // Note that AVCaptureVideoDataOutput connection does NOT support hardware-accelerated
    // rotation and mirroring via videoOrientation and setVideoMirrored properties so we
    // need to do the rotation in software here.
    cv::transpose(mat, mat);
    CGFloat temp = rect.size.width;
    rect.size.width = rect.size.height;
    rect.size.height = temp;

    if (videOrientation == AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        // flip around y axis for back camera
        cv::flip(mat, mat, 1);
    }
    else {
        // Front camera output needs to be mirrored to match preview layer so no flip is required here
    }

    videOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;

    // Detect faces
    std::vector<cv::Rect> faces;
    std::vector<cv::Rect> eyes;


    _faceCascade.detectMultiScale(mat, faces, 1.1, 2, 0 |CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, cv::Size(30, 30));

    // We will usually have only one face in frame
    if (faces.size() >0){
        cv::Mat faceROI = mat(faces.front());
        _eyesCascade.detectMultiScale( faceROI, eyes, 1.15, 3.0, 0 , cv::Size(30, 30));
    }

    // Dispatch updating of face markers to main queue
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self displayFaces:faces eyes:eyes
             forVideoRect:rect
          videoOrientation:videOrientation];    
    });
}
```

Comment: I was also looking into eye detection with opencv and it seems to be quite low-quality. Two approaches I am investigating are a completely new detector, based on the many research papers on the topic, and a new classifier, trained with my own data. Both of them are time-consuming.

Comment: So may be openCV will not provide a proper solution. Do you know about CIDetector performance that is apple inbuilt functionality for eye detection and other stuff. I also found this video of a faceL project which seems to be giving robust result. But could not find any implementation for iPhone. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQA_Do1mZ9E.

Comment: If all you want is to build an iPhone app with some support for eye detection, the iPhone SDK is the way to go. OpenCV offers you an impressive range of tools to develop custom detectors, which you can port to other platforms or extend, but the required resources are beyond what an usual app developer affords - it may require months of work and a lot of math, just for this feature.